# sql query with two tables having reference key

Tags: sql, isqlquery

I have two tables:

```
Discounts(disid primary key)

Cust(custid primary key, disid ref discount(disid))
```

Now I need a query to get `custid` having all `disid`(discount coupons) and the customer may contain the same `disid` more than once.

Comment: A simple join won't do it? If not more info needed

Answer (score 1):

```
select custid, count(distinct disid) from cust
group by custid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from discounts)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D.disid) FROM CUST C 
INNER JOIN DISCOUNTS D ON D.disid=C.disid GROUP BY D.disid
```

Answer (score 1):

try either of this solutions:

```
SELECT  a.custid, COUNT(a.disid) totalCoupon
FROM    cust a  
            INNER JOIN discounts b 
                ON b.disid = a.disid 
GROUP BY a.custid
```

or

```
SELECT  a.custid, COUNT(a.disid) totalCoupon
FROM    cust a  
            INNER JOIN discounts b 
                ON b.disid = a.disid 
GROUP BY a.custid
HAVING   COUNT(a.disid) > 1 -- customers having the same (but more than 1) 
                            -- CouponID will only be shown here
```